# X is a normal random variable and Y=g(X) , Y is standart normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$X$ is a gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$ .$Y=g(X)$  is also gaussianly distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$ . Find $g(.)$

I can't figure out how i need to solve this. I' ve tried using Expected value and variance equation, i 've tried to go pdf from cdf. I might 've got little confused about $g(.)$ Can you help me please, thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to, i did it now :D

Answer (score 1):

$Y = g(X) = X - \mu$ gives a Gaussian RV with a mean = ?
Once you solve that, think about the transformation you can apply to normalize the variance (i.e. change the variance from $\sigma^2$ to $1$).
Be careful to use the capital $X$ for $Y=g(X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation i will try that and i 've edited for Y=g(X) , but where is this come from X−μ = g(X)

Comment: Try drawing the distributions as pictures on paper to understand where the motivation for the initial transformation comes from.

Comment: Okay, i 'll try to do it. Thank you again :D